# Maven plugin inheritance from pluginManagement

Tags: maven, build, maven-2

there

I have a parent pom.xml which defines the the default configuration for maven-ear-plugin

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <modules>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
                        <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
                        <artifactId>artifact2</artifactId>
                    </jarModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

In the child pom, I defined the maven-ear-plugin in the `<plugins>` section

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-ear</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>ear</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <earSourceDirectory>EarContent</earSourceDirectory>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>APP-INF/lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <modules>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
                        <artifactId>artifact3</artifactId>
                    </jarModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

My intention is to include all 3 jar files artifact1, artifact2 and artifact3 in the ear. However, after the build, only artifact3 defined in child pom.xml is included. So it looks like by default the `<modules>` definition in the child pom.xml overwrites what's defined in the parent pom, instead of **merge** them together. In fact, if I remove the whole `<modules>` section in the child pom.xml, the artifact1 and artifact2 will be included after the build.

My question is whether there is a way to include all jar modules defined in parent pom and child pom. I have several ear projects and all of them need to include the same set of jar modules plus a few jar modules of their own. I am trying to move the common set of jar modules to the parent so that they are not repeated in each child pom.xml.

**Update to clarify my projects relations:**

```
parent pom.xml (define maven-ear-plugin in the pluginManagement section)
  -- project1 pom.xml (multi-module project)
      -- myJar-proj1 
      -- myWeb-proj1
      -- myEar-proj1 (define maven-ear-plugin in the <build> section)    
  -- project2 pom.xml (multi-module project)
      -- myJar-proj2
      -- myWeb-proj2
      -- myEar-proj2 (define maven-ear-plugin in the <build> section)
```

Comment: i am assuming that you have defined the plugin directly under the build , not under the pluginManagement under build. is it a correct statement ?? - thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to achieve the merge behavior you should put the `maven-ear-plugin` [under the `plugins`](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) tag in the parent `pom` (rather than [under `pluginManagement`](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management)).

Parent `pom`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <modules>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
                        <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
                        <artifactId>artifact2</artifactId>
                    </jarModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**EDIT**

After OP's clarified projects structure: the attribute `combine.children="append"` on the `modules` element, in the child projects:

```
<modules combine.children="append">
    <jarModule>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact3</artifactId>
    </jarModule>
</modules>
```

The parent should still define the plugin only in `pluginManagement`.

Comment: I cannot do that. If I do so, all child projects would have the maven-ear-plugin enabled. I have a classic multi-module maven project setting. The ear project is just one of the child projects. There are also jar/war projects that are sibling of the ear project.

Comment: @Lan You shouldn't define the `maven-ear-plugin` in the parent of all projects, rather only in the child ear-project that is the parent of all ear projects.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify my project relations. I assume you suggest defining the maven-ear-plugin in the project1 and project2 pom.xml, under <build>. I see 2 drawbacks. First, each maven-ear-plugin defintion has to list all the jar modules. I prefer to define the common jar modules in the top parent pom.xml. Secondly, if I define the maven-ear-plugin in the build section of project1 and project2, all the child projects such as myJar-proj1, myWeb-proj2 will have the maven-ear-plugin. That's not what I want. We only want the maven-ear-plugin in the myEar-proj1 and myEar-proj2.